# Default date formatting

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, mysql, jquery-ui

How do I change `defaultDate: "+1w"` to this format: `yyyy-mm-dd`? It must display like that in the input field.

JavaScript here:

```
<script>
$(function() {
        var dates = $( "#from").datepicker({
        defaultDate: "+1w",
        changeMonth: true,
        numberOfMonths: 1,
    onSelect: function( selectedDate ) {
    var option = this.id == "from" ? "minDate" : "maxDate",
    instance = $( this ).data( "datepicker" ),
    date = $.datepicker.parseDate(
        instance.settings.dateFormat ||
        $.datepicker._defaults.dateFormat,
        selectedDate, instance.settings );
                    dates.not( this ).datepicker( "option", option, date );
        }
    });
});
</script>
```

php code here:

```
<?php
$IMG_DIR_URL = "./digits/";
$date = date("d F Y");
?>
```

Displaying contents here:

```
 <div class="field">
        <label>Date</label>
        <input type="text" name="date" value="<?php value('date'); ?>" id="from" /> 

        <?php if(isset($errors['date'])) { ?>
        <div class="error"><?php echo $errors['date']; ?></div>
        <?php } ?>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

use `date('Y-m-d')` for yyyy-mm-dd with the PHP date function.

you can format it in the datepicker options by adding `dateformat: 'yy-mm-dd',` like so:

```
$(function() {
        var dates = $( "#from").datepicker({
        defaultDate: "+1w",
        changeMonth: true,
        numberOfMonths: 1,
        dateformat: 'yy-mm-dd',
    onSelect: function( selectedDate ) {
    var option = this.id == "from" ? "minDate" : "maxDate",
    instance = $( this ).data( "datepicker" ),
    date = $.datepicker.parseDate(
        instance.settings.dateFormat ||
        $.datepicker._defaults.dateFormat,
        selectedDate, instance.settings );
                    dates.not( this ).datepicker( "option", option, date );
        }
    });
});
```

I don't know what your value function does, but if it doesn't show the date
your PHP for displaying it should be:

```
<input type="text" name="date" value="<?php echo $date; ?>" id="from" />
```

Comment: didn't seem to work, you sure I mustn't change the javaScript defaultDate: "+1w"